# Redirect the dependency property

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have in a `MyForm` a `UserControlA` in whtich I have an other `UserControlB`.
*UserControlB* has a (dependency) property `FooB`.
Each time *FooB* changes I need to change `MyForm.FormTextBox1.Text`.

How should I "transport" the *FooB* changes to the *MyForm*?

Via an another DependencyProperty in *UserControlA*?

Comment: Have you read about binding at all?

Comment: @Phil, yes, some basic information.

Comment: I suppose it should work as intended if you just do it as you wrote: create another `DependencyProperty` in `UserControlA` and bind it to `FooB`. Moreover, I suppose that if `UserControlB` is inside `UserControlA`, then `UserControlA` itself should expose all the properties you need to use it, so you shouldn't try to use properties of `UserControlB` directly in this case. This way `UserControlB` is encapsulated and the code is more organised :).